# How do I change *only* the task bar color in Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp

I know I can change the taskbar color by going to Properties -> Advanced, and changing the color for "3D objects". Unfortunately, when I do that, a bunch of menus also change color, and I don't want that. Is there a way to change only the taskbar?

Comment: What do you mean by "task bar color"?  Which part of the Task bar?

Comment: The entire background of the taskbar. The thing that is grey in classic Windows and blue/green in XP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it is a 3D item, the only way to change it without skinning your system using something like WindowBlinds or the like is to change the color of all 3D elements in the system.